# How are interface methods able to be utilised without having to implement them?

Tags: java, http, servlets, interface

This is a basic Java interface question but in the context of servlets.

I understand that interfaces are fully abstract in that none of their methods can have implementations unlike abstract classes. 
HttpServletRequest is an interface. When creating servlets, doPost() and doGet() methods make use of this interface with the code:

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){ // implementation }
```

My questions are:

- What are request and response? Are they objects?
- Given that interface methods are not implemented and that we aren’t generally required to implement the interface’s methods when creating the servlet, how do the methods of ‘request’ get implemented as seen in the code.

  ```
  request.getParameter()
  ```

Comment: These are objects that implement the interface. The objects are created by the server (Tomcat, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are request and response? Are they objects?

They are just references, pointing to some objects, just like any other reference. Nothing special here.

> how do the methods of ‘request’ get implemented as seen in the code.

`HttpServletRequest` is just an API, whose implementation are provided by the servlet container you're using (probably tomcat). Internally, for every request, the container would create object of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` implementation, and pass it to your `doPost` or `doGet` method.

Comment: So do you mean to say that response is a reference to an object created by Tomcat that implements the methods stated in HttpServletResponse interface and that whenever you call response.getParameter(), you're actually using the getParameter() method of the object referred to by response?

Comment: Also if it is the case that the servlet container creates the object for you, aren't we being dependent on that container? I mean in a more general case, we wouldn't simply be able use the interface by declaring a reference in a similar way unless we ourselves implement it right?

Comment: @user3111418 `HttpServletRequest` is a part of Servlet specification. Tomcat container, and other containers for that matter are implementation for those specification. The implementation they provide should comply with the specs. And yes you're dependent on those containers. One can build his/her own container also that complies with the servlet specs, and you can deploy the application there. No big deal. But the fact is, someone has to provide the implementation.

Comment: So even though you're dependent on tomcat container, you're not tightly coupled with it. You can use any other container.

Answer (score 1):

You get a reference of object of a class which actually implement `HttpServletRequest`.

Now how you get that object, well the webserver initialize those object and call your `doGet` or `doPost` method by passing those reference  as parameter.